# Wrong URI being passed through, hardcoding the URI works

Tags: java, android, uri, image

Ok so in this piece of code, I am trying to get the URI of my file that I saved automatically, and I want to put it into a bitmap image. This all works when I hardcode the picture location as you can see. But when I use the commented code it doesn't return a correct URI, and I don't know why because it should work?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == FOTO_NEMEN && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        final File file = temp;
        try {
            String urienzo = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0191.jpg";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(urienzo);
            //Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            //Bitmap foto2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
            Bitmap foto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(urienzo);
            if (foto == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, ":(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
```

If anyone could point me into the right direction for finding the correct URI from a picture I just took and saved (like it takes the last taken picture), they would be a lifesaver.

When I hardcode it, `uri.toSring()` returns

```
/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0191.jpg
```

and when I use the `Uri.fromFile(file);` it returns

`file:///data/data/gip.chillax/cache/tijdelijk-687168107.jpg`

so it's obviously not correct

Comment: can you show what `uri.toString()` gives you in both versions?

Comment: @jlordo         so when I hardcode it, it's `/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAG0191.jpg` and when I use the `Uri.fromFile(file);` it's `file:///data/data/gip.chillax/cache/tijdelijk-687168107.jpg` so it's obviously not correct

Comment: Then `temp` must be the wrong file and the error is somewhere in the code you didn't post. Also, include this kind of information in your question for future visitors (you can use the _edit_ button).